# How to create online users list using webrtc and nodejs on the server end

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am using webrtc to make a audio, video and chat application where I need keep all the users in a user list in the serverside. Need help how to get this done.

Also, how can I remove users from the list when they logout from the system.

Need help to implement this.

```
 webRTC.rtc.on('connect', function(rtc) {
 //Client connected
 });

 webRTC.rtc.on('send answer', function(rtc) {
 //answer sent
 });

 webRTC.rtc.on('disconnect', function(rtc) {
 //Client disconnect
     //console.log(webRTC);
 });

 webRTC.rtc.on('chat_msg', function(data, socket) {
     var roomList = webRTC.rtc.rooms[data.room] || [];

     for (var i = 0; i < roomList.length; i++) {
         var socketId = roomList[i];

         if (socketId !== socket.id) {
             var soc = webRTC.rtc.getSocket(socketId);

             if (soc) {
                 soc.send(JSON.stringify({
                     "eventName": "receive_chat_msg",
                     "data": {
                     "messages": data.messages,
                     "id": data.id,
                     "from": data.from,
                     "status": data.status,
                     "email": data.email
                     }
                 }), function(error) {
                     if (error) {
                     console.log(error);
                 }
                 });
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: You can fire socket.emit('new-user', username)....

in onbeforeunload; fire socket.emit('remove-user', username).....

socket.on('disconnect') is not useful in your case..... 

I prefer objects over arrays!....

var users = {}; 

socket.on('new-user', function(username) { 
     users[username] = username; 
}); 

...... and 

socket.on('remove-user', function(username) {
    var user = users[username];
    if(user) delete users[username];
});

Comment: Thanks Muaz, I have added the server code. It would be great if you can help me how to get it done as you suggested. I am using "webRTC.rtc.on" where as you suggested of using "socket.on". I am using webrtc.io library and it seems that the suggested one is using socket.io. Is there no other way other than onbeforeunload, as it doesn't seem reliable always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was using webrtc.io module, so below are the methods that helped me to create the userlist and maintain the presence.

`webRTC.rtc.on('join_room', function(data, socket) {

// Will get info who joined along with his socket id

}`

And

`webRTC.rtc.on('room_leave', function(room, socketid) {

// Will get info who left the room

}`

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js code:**

```
var users = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connect', true);

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    });

    socket.on('new-user', function (username) {
        users[username] = username;
    });

    socket.on('check-presence', function (username) {
        var isUserPresent = !! users[username];
        socket.emit('presence', isUserPresent);
    });

    socket.on('remove-user', function (username) {
        var user = users[username];
        if (user) delete users[username];
    });
});
```

**This may also work (node.js):**

```
var users = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var UserName;

    socket.emit('connect', true);
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    });

    socket.on('new-user', function (username) {
        users[username] = username;
        UserName = username;
    });

    socket.on('check-presence', function (username) {
        var isUserPresent = !! users[username];
        socket.emit('presence', isUserPresent);
    });

    // removing user on "disconnect"
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var user = users[UserName];
        if (user) delete users[UserName];
    });
});
```

**For 1st case; client-side code:**

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('new-user', 'username');
});

function removeUser() {
    socket.emit('remove-user', 'username');
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    removeUser();
};

// if someone pressed "F5" key to refresh the page
window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116)
        removeUser();
};

// if someone leaves via <a href>
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'),
    length = anchors.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var a = anchors[i];
    if (a.href.indexOf('#') !== 0 && a.getAttribute('target') != '_blank')
        a.onclick = function () {
            removeUser();
        };
}
```

**For 2nd case; client side code:**

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('new-user', 'username');
});
```

**You can check presence too:**

```
socket.on('presence', isUserPresent) {
    // boolean: user is present or not
});

socket.emit('check-presence', 'username');
```